# Combine toggle and fadeTo in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way I can toggle the `fadeTo()` method in jquery? Does a specific method exist for this or do I have to use conditionals to achieve that?

Comment: I think you may be looking for the [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) method; but without some idea of the values you're trying to use with `fadeTo()`, or what you're doing in your code, it's very hard to say. Please read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines to see how to ask a 'good' question; because as asked we're unable to offer any specific help, or clearly understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method specifically for this - the **[`.fadeToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)** method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: but how can I make an element toggle between an opacity of 0.7 and 0.3 for example?

Comment: Not sure why you'd *want* to do that, but you'd need to make use of conditional logic on the regular `.fadeTo()` method for that. Set up variables as the start and end opacity points. Then check what the current opacity is, and invert them if need be.